# Enum values in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a enum class like,

```
public enum USERTYPE
{
   Permanant=1,
   Temporary=2,
}
```

in my business object I just declare this enum as

```
private List<USERTYPE> userType=new List<USERTYPE>;
```

and in the get/set method, I tried like

```
public List<USERTYPE> UserType
    {
        get 
        {
            return userType;
        }
        set
        { 
            userType= value; 
        }
    }
```

here it returns the no of rows as 0, how can I get all the values in the Enum here, can anyone help me here...

Comment: Are you *filling* that list before reading the number of rows ?

Comment: @Shanish take alook at here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that you actually want a List of USERTYPE?

Comment: Enum.GetValues(typeof(USERTYPE)).Cast<USERTYPE>().ToList(); this works actually, thanks everyone

Comment: @davenewza ya I want a list of USERTYPE, its working,thanks for ur support

Comment: @Alex sorry I dont understand

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use this to get all individual enum values:

```
private List<USERTYPE> userTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(USERTYPE)).Cast<USERTYPE>().ToList();
```

If you do things like this more often, you could create a generic utility method for it:

```
public static T[] GetEnumValues<T>() where T : struct {
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) {
        throw new ArgumentException("GetValues<T> can only be called for types derived from System.Enum", "T");
    }
    return (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Not very elegant since `Enumerable.Cast` enumerates your array, all members are boxed and then unboxed, and `Enumerable.ToList` enumerates and creates a new `List<>`. But I can understand why people use ugly solutions like this when the .NET Framework has not provided a generic version of `Enum.GetValues`.

Comment: To anyone who couldn't find Cast() or ToList(), this requires you to include System.Linq

Answer (score 6):

`GetValues` returns `System.Array`, but we know it's really a `TEnum[]` (that is a one-dimensional array indexed from zero) where `TEnum` is `USERTYPE` in your case. Therefore use:

```
var allUsertypeValues = (USERTYPE[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(USERTYPE));
```

Answer (score 4):

UserTypeCan you please try with that,

```
 UserType = Enum.GetValues(typeof(USERTYPE)).OfType<USERTYPE>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is basically List of enum. Not individual items inside that enum.

To get list of enum values you can do

```
string[] str = Enum.GetNames(typeof(USERTYPE));
```

To use in get/set return string[] instead of List<>

```
public string[] UserType
{
    get 
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(USERTYPE));
    }
}
```

I think set will not work here because you cannot add values in enum at runtime.

Comment: how can I use this in Get/Set

Comment: thanks Nikhil and pratap, for ur support, actually Botz solution is working for me

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get specific enum value from the list `user.UserType` then you first need to `Add` enum value to this list:

```
var user = new User();
//1 value - PERMANENT
user.UserType.Add(USERTYPE.Permanent);
```

But if you only need to get all the possible values from an arbitrary `enum` then you can try `Enum.GetValues`

```
//2 values - Permanant and Temporary
var enums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(USERTYPE));
```