# Dynamically store multiple enum's in a List C#

Tags: c#, types, enums

I want to store a list of enum's in a C# list. I don't want to store an enum value but rather an enum. My goal is to ask a user to name some enum's that they want and store them in the list so I can traverse the list later.

So for example, I'll ask what categories of food are they interested in and they'll specify meats, vegetables, dairy, fruits, etc.  Depending on what they want, I will tell them what's available.

If the user says the want to know about the meats and fruits categories, I will print out all enumerated meats and fruits like so...

```
beef, pork, chicken, apple, orange, banana
```

My enums  will be defined like so...

```
enum meats {beef, pork, chicken};
enum vegetables {corn, lettuce, tomato, carrots, broccoli};
enum dairy {cheese, milk, yougurt};
enum fruits {apple, orange, banana};
```

Since the user picked meats and vegetables, I would like to add it to a List<> then traverse that list and print out all items in each enum.
Semantically it would look like...

```
List<enum> toPrint = new List<enum>();  //list of enum "categories"
ShopperList(meats);
ShopperList(fruits);

void ShopperList(enum category){
     toPrint.Add(category);
}

void PrintCategories(toPrint){
     foreach (enum category in toPrint){
          foreach(string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(category)){
               Console.WriteLine(name + ", ");
          }
     }
}
```

I get an error saying "Type expected" from the compiler on the line where I define the List variable. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: `rather an enum` I assume you mean `typeof(theenumhere)`?

Comment: You´d need a `List<Type>`, that stores the actual **types**, not the **values**.

Comment: probable duplicate <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240236/enum-values-in-a-list>

Comment: I have an added layer of complexity compared to that question

Comment: Yes, a loop around the actual types. That shouldn´t be a huge problem though.

Comment: I wonder how this design is useful to order something? Generics? Imho you shouldn't use enums, rather something like a key to identify product, ideally a database table. The product can contain additional properties to classify it better, like category, which is in turn also table.

Comment: Correct HimBromBeere, which is the main point of this question whereas the other question is about printing the enum values. imo, they're two different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You´d need a `List<Type>`, that stores the actual **types**, not the **value**s

```
List<Type> toPrint = new List<Type>();  //list of enum "categories"
ShopperList(typeof(meats));
ShopperList(typeof(fruits));

void ShopperList(Type category){
     toPrint.Add(category);
}

void PrintCategories(List<Type> toPrint){
     foreach (Type category in toPrint){
          foreach(string name in Enum.GetNames(category)){
               Console.WriteLine(name + ", ");
          }
     }
}
```

As `Type` can be **anything**, including e.g. `string`, `MyClass` or just `object`, you should further filter on `Type.IsEnum` within your loop:

```
foreach (Type category in toPrint.Where(x => x.IsEnum))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a compiler error on the ShopperList(typeof(meats)) and the same function call for fruits. The compiler is complaining about 
error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `Program.ShopperList(System.Type)'

Comment: @starvingPhilosopher Either make the method `static`, or create an instance of `Program` in order to call its method.

Comment: Thanks @HimBromBeere, I made all the methods static and it worked. There  were other good suggestions on implementing a solution for this as well but this directly answered my "How To" question. Thanks to all commenters!

Answer (score 0):

An enum value is by default an int.

It seems you want to use polymorphism.

It is impossible with enums.

You may use classes.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{

  public abstract class Food { }

  public abstract class Meat : Food { }
  public class Beef : Meat { }
  public class Chicken : Meat { }

  public abstract class Vegetable : Food { }
  public class Lettuce : Vegetable { }
  public class Tomato : Vegetable { }
  public class Carrots : Vegetable { }

  class Program
  {

    static List<Type> toPrint = new List<Type>();

    static string GetCategories(List<Type> list)
    {
      var result = new List<string>();
      foreach ( var item in list )
        foreach ( var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() )
          if ( type.IsSubclassOf(item) )
            result.Add(type.Name);
      return String.Join(", ", result.ToArray());
    }

    static void Main()
    {

      toPrint.Add(typeof(Meat));
      toPrint.Add(typeof(Vegetable));

      Console.WriteLine(GetCategories(toPrint));
      Console.ReadKey();

    }
  }

}
```

It prints:

```
Beef, Chicken, Lettuce, Tomato, Carrots
```